# Java Regular Expression for finding specific string

Tags: java, regex

I have a file with a long string a I would like to split it by specific  item  i.e.

```
String line = "{{[Metadata{"this, is my first, string"}]},{[Metadata{"this, is my second, string"}]},{[Metadata{"this, is my third string"}]}}"

String[] tab = line.split("(?=\\bMetadata\\b)");
```

So now when I iterate my tab I will get lines starting from word: `"Metadata"` but  I would like lines starting from:

```
"{[Metadata"
```

I've tried something like:

```
 String[] tab = line.split("(?=\\b{[Metadata\\b)");
```

but it doesnt work.
Can anyone help me how to do that, plese?

Comment: You may try `"(?=\\{\\[Metadata\\b)"`. See https://ideone.com/LwB7Z2

Comment: Yes, this one works :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?=\{\[Metadata\b)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ya4xLv/1/).

---

Note that the backslashes need to be escaped in `Java` so that it becomes

```
(?=\\{\\[Metadata\\b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution using a formal pattern matcher.  We can try matching your content using the following regex:

```
(?<=Metadata\\{\")[^\"]+
```

This uses a lookbehind to check for the `Metadata` marker, ending with a double quote.  Then, it matches any content up to the closing double quote.

```
String line = "{{[Metadata{\"this, is my first, string\"}]},{[Metadata{\"this, is my second, string\"}]},{[Metadata{\"this, is my third string\"}]}}";
String pattern = "(?<=Metadata\\{\")[^\"]+";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

while (m.find( )) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}

this, is my first, string
this, is my second, string
this, is my third string
```